# Size of seeds for numpy.random

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I want to run some code using `numpy.random` and keep track of what the seed is so that if the output is interesting, I can recreate and play around with that randomly generated instance. Therefore, I want the setup to involve something like

```
import numpy as np
s = np.random.randint(10000000000)
print(s)
np.random.seed(s)
### remainder of code
```

so that the code is still running randomly, but I also have retained the seed `s`. The value `10000000000` was chosen arbitrarily; what is the appropriate scale for `numpy.random`'s seeding? e.g. are seeds all the same modulo 2^32?

Comment: So you’re using the numpy random generator to generate a seed for the numpy random generator? What do you think that accomplishes? If you trust the randomness of the generator is good enough to give you a seed, why not just use the generator? If you want reproducibility for validation or debugging purposes, you should be using a fixed seed value rather than a randomized one.

Comment: I want to run random experiments but be able to reproduce some of the outputs from different trials. The ideal would be to know what the initial under-the-hood seed is, and this is a way to functionally accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use the time as a seed or SHA-256 as it's a standard rather than just a 32-bit int, here is an example of how to use the time, depending on your usecase.

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Use current time as seed value
s = int(time.time())
print("Seed value:", s)

np.random.seed(s)
# Generate random numbers
```